# TabControl AddingTab event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a `TabControl` in which I want to prevent adding existing `TabPage` (they are identified by a name) and instead set the `SelectedTabPage` to this precise tab.

I wish to know if there are an event that triggers right before a page is being added to the `TabControl`. If not, would using the event `CollectionChanged` of the `TabPages` (list) be a correct alternative ?

Comment: A TabControl should always be a private variable of your Form class.  The user himself can't add any pages.  So normally it is only your own code that can add a page.  Which begs the question why you are trying to protect yourself against your own code.  It isn't like external code doesn't have any other way to get a page added, if it really wants to.  A tab control is accessible to UI Automation.  And Reflection is always a back-door.  Stopping that takes drastic measures.

Comment: I agree with Hans Passant, your requirement is so strange and not practical.

Comment: @Hans Passant In visual studio, you cannot open two instance of a document inside a project. Instead, it invokes the existing instance and set the SelectedTab to this same instance. This is the exact behavior I was looking for.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  You select a tab page by clicking on a tab, nothing is "opened".  If you want to prevent selection of a page then just write an event handler for the Selecting event and set e.Cancel = true.

Comment: When you double click on a file, the file opens. When you are doing so again, it won't create the TabPage, but set it to the SelectedTab.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the event you're looking for is the `Control.ControlAdded` event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded.aspx

If that also detects when things inside the tab pages themselves are added, you should be able to filter out everything but `TabPage` controls using the `ControlEventArgs.Control` property in your event handler.

To reject adding a control will be a little more complicated.  Since this event seems to only be raised *after* the control gets added, you'll need to do something like this:

```
void onControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
    var tab = e as TabPage;

    if (tab == null)
        return;

    this.myTabControlObject.TabPages.Remove(tab);
}
```

This *should* remove the tab, but it will likely slow the tab adding process considerably.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the control from being added ? I can only see a way to access the added control with this event.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, I am checking the `TabControl` page Collection for a page with the same name as the Page that is trying to be added, if it exists I am setting focus to the existing instance, otherwise adding the new page to the `TabControl`.  See if something like this works for you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage tp = new TabPage();
    tp.Name = tabPage1.Name;
    var temp =tabControl1.Controls.Find(tp.Name,true);
    if( temp.Length > 0)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = (TabPage) temp[0];
    }
    else
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tp);
}
```

---

Anything having to do with the [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) will most likely be triggered after the control has been added.

From above link:

> You can determine if a Control is a member of the collection by passing the control into the Contains method. To get the index value of the location of a Control in the collection, pass the control into the IndexOf method. The collection can be copied into an array by calling the CopyTo method.

---

If you want you could cleanup your code some by adding an `ExtensionMethod` to your `TabControl` Check for an existing page, set focus or add from there.

Example:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static bool AddPage(this TabControl tc, TabPage tp)
        {
            var matchedPages = tc.Controls.Find(tp.Name, false);
            if ( matchedPages.Length > 0)
            {
                tc.SelectedTab = (TabPage)matchedPages[0];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                tc.TabPages.Add(tp);
                tc.SelectedTab = tp;
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
tabControl1.AddPage(tp);
```

Comment: I previously had a similar solution, but I was wondering if it was possible to handle it directly in the collection or the tab control.

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp see my edit, since you are dealing with the Name being the same even though they are physically different instances, the Find method would work. As far as I can see the only other methods would be responding to after the Page was added.