# Event raised by TabControl after change

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I want to respond to `TabControl` changes. So if `TabItem` have been added I want to know about that. What's important is that I'm interested in an event that gets raised **after** `TabItem` have been added and **not** when the underlying `ItemsSource` collection changes.

Hooking up to `StatusChanged` event of `ItemContainerGenerator` doesn't do the trick because it's not raised when I need it to:

```
ContentTabs.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622315/tabcontrol-addingtab-event+#

Comment: Well, not exactly. That guy is looking for an event that is raised BEFORE tab is added :)

Comment: There's no `ControlAdded` event on TabControl: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx (events section). Look at this question's tags - I'm using WPF.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch My bad.

Comment: What code adds the tab control? Can you do it there?

Comment: Does it matter? My `TabControl` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. When item is added to it, the `TabControl` updates itself... Nothing fancy here :)